# Error accessing a Web Service with SSL

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ibm-jdk, ibm-jvm

I have a program that is supposed to send a file to a web service, which requires an SSL connection. I run the program as follows:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07
SET com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=ssl.client.props
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ".;Test.jar" ca.mypackage.Main
```

This was works fine, but when I change the first line to

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre
```

I get the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:140)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:86)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:593)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:552)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:537)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:434)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:132)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:242)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:115)
at $Proxy26.fileSubmit(Unknown Source)
at com.testing.TestingSoapProxy.fileSubmit(TestingSoapProxy.java:81)
at ca.mypackage.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.a(SSLSocketFactory.java:7)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:1)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:110)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:14)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:902)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:86)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:107)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
at javax.net.ssl.SSLJsseUtil.b(SSLJsseUtil.java:20)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:36)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:16)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:36)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.<init>(b.java:1)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:11)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:995)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.EndpointAddress.openConnection(EndpointAddress.java:206)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.createHttpConnection(HttpClientTransport.java:277)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:103)
... 14 more
```

So it seems that this problem would be related to the JRE I'm using, but what doesn't seem to make sense is that the non-IBM JRE works fine, but the IBM JRE does not. Any ideas, or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your non IBM jre is sun, then it already comes with SSL classes implementation packaged along with it.

It seems the IBM jre is not containing SSL implementation classes at all.

Comment: To clarify it a bit as it is slightly incorrect. The JRE referred in question is WAS JRE. Every IBM JRE contains SSL classes, but this one is not supposed to be used for standalone Java programs and it contains configuration for SSL provider which is included in the WAS libraries. If you are using it with without WebSphere you need to override `ssl.SocketFactory.provider` and `ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider` from `java.security`

Answer (score 21):

Try adding these two lines somewhere in your setup code:

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
```

Comment: I've done this and now I get following exception: java.security.KeyStoreException: IBMKeyManager: Problem accessing key store java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect. Looks like I need to put "changeme" somewhere?

Comment: @Anton - Where to add this configuration?

Comment: @SK. I left IBM and Websphere stack for good six years ago, I can't remember...

Comment: @SK you can just use a static initializer for this; it only needs to be done once

Answer (score 9):

Java only allows one SSL connection factory class for a JVM.  If you are using a JDK thats shipped with WebSphere Application Server v6x/7x/8x  or any other WebSphere server tools in Rational Application Developer, then  those  require IBM ( com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory ) specific class from WebSphere Application Server runtime.
because the java security file has the JSSE socket factories set like below

```
# Default JSSE socket factories
#ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
#ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl

# WebSphere socket factories (in cryptosf.jar)
ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLServerSocketFactory
```

So, If you uncomment the Default JSSE Socket factories and comment out the WebSphere ones then WAS is going to puke.

Better work around  would be to have  com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar file in your class path. This jar file has a dependency on com.ibm.ffdc.jar file so you need that in your class path well. Both these jarfiles are available under `<WebSphere_Install_Dirctory>/plugins/`

Comment: I may be lucky, but using the Default JSSE socket factories (with the WebSphere one commented out) seem to work for me.  Now I can use the JDK with my CI builds.

Answer (score 3):

One more "solution" which seems to be working for me. Create your own security properties file, `my.java.security` with contents like:

```
ssl.SocketFactory.provider=
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=
```

When calling Java (or in my case maven), add the command line option:

```
-Djava.security.properties=C:\myfiles\my.java.security
```

Cribbed from the IBM Liberty documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_trouble.html?lang=en

Comment: Make sure security.overrideProperties=true in java.security file under JDK to allow overriding

Answer (score 2):

one may set these properties at WAS_HOME/*/java/jre/lib/security/java.security file by uncomenting the following JSSE props.

## Default JSSE socket factories

ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl

Comment: you need to comment out the websphere ones that are after it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this topic while searching for the same error message but found a different solution.
To test a https REST service using the Apache Wink client:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.setBypassHostnameVerification(true);
RestClient client = new RestClient(config);
```

And set the Factory's empty:

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "");
Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "");
```

My runtime is a standalone Camel test using IBM JRE 1.7 from IBM WebSphere v8.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when my Batch application was trying to fetch data from Restful web service using Apache wink. I was using MyEclipse as my dev environment. And was using the jre provided by IBM webSphere 8.5. When I changed to Sun 1.6 jre, the issue got resolved.