# Java/Websphere NoSuchProviderException: IBMCertPath

Tags: unix, ssl, websphere, java-security

I've recently inherited a task at my company that involves implementing an application that has currently been running off an employee's windows desktop, and migrating that code to Unix Server used for the office.

The server also runs IBM's websphere, which contains many of the companies larger web applications and uses java 1.6.

Organizational points aside (this is a huge company and much of the coding looks like a spaghetti western, with old legacy systems I wouldn't be suprised if people don't have any idea about), my plans was simply downgrade the code (which was simple as it was from 1.7 to 1.6), then move this application to a runnable jar, and call it via a shell script.

I, however, realize now why this application was never migrated to our production server, as I can't get the thing to run in the UNIX system.

First, I ran into an issue where (and I may be wrong about this) the SSL connections used as part of the application throws an error (same error as this question: [Error accessing a Web Service with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776149/error-accessing-a-web-service-with-ssl)) After some reading, it seems that any java application run on a server with Websphere (if the application is not in websphere) cannot be done, and thus you have to manually set some java Security Properties to do this (which i did right at the opening of my main method).

After doing that, I get past the initial error, but I am now getting this error

```
"com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: IBMCertPath"
```

If this has already been asked, I'm sorry, but I couldn't seem to find it. Please link it here and i will close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because something has specified to use the IBMCertPath provider, but java security doesn't know what that provider is.

You need to ensure that com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath is in the provider list in your java.security file.  See:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/gen_info_sec_prov.html

Comment: This is correct, although i thought i had checked it.  I had to verify the correct $JAVA_HOME directory (I was looking at the wrong file).  In the correct file, there were spelling errors in that provider line from somebody editing it, causing it to be missing. Thank you for your answer in any case